# Android application died when using OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv, camera, surfaceview

I'm using OpenCV for my application (third tutorial - camera control - from OpenCV samples).

```
private int frameRate = 0;

public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

    mGray = inputFrame.gray();

    if (frameRate == 20){
        String rec = NativeLib.recognize(0,mGray.getNativeObjAddr(),mNetworkPath);
        //Core.putText(mGray, rec, new Point(50,50),  Core.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.0, sc,2);
        frameRate = 0;
    }
    ++frameRate;

    return mGray;
}
```

Problem is that after some time, the application stops working. This is the console output:

```
03-21 20:42:24.780: D/JavaCameraView(4211): Preview Frame received. Frame size: 460800
03-21 20:42:24.850: D/JavaCameraView(4211): Preview Frame received. Frame size: 460800
03-21 20:42:24.920: D/JavaCameraView(4211): Preview Frame received. Frame size: 460800
03-21 20:42:24.980: D/JavaCameraView(4211): Preview Frame received. Frame size: 460800
03-21 20:42:25.050: D/JavaCameraView(4211): Preview Frame received. Frame size: 460800
03-21 20:42:25.070: D/kernel(145): [ 3658.389068] bq27520 0-0055: bq27520_handle_soc_worker() capacity=81 (81) flags=0x129 ctrl_status=0x28b soh_state=0x3, valid=1
03-21 20:42:25.120: I/ActivityManager(288): Process myapp.mobile.test (pid 4211) has died.
03-21 20:42:25.120: I/caladbolg(153): 3649386385 cald_camctrl.c                    (4583)  4226 P [SVR] -645580942 + Cald_CamCtrl_ICamera_CancelAutoLock
03-21 20:42:25.120: I/caladbolg(153): 3649386476 cald_camctrl.c                    (9440)  4226 P [SVR] -645580820 + Cald_CamCtrl_FSM_Func_CancelAutoLock
03-21 20:42:25.120: I/caladbolg(153): 3649386507 cald_camctrl.c                    (9463)  4226 P [SVR] -645580789 - Cald_CamCtrl_FSM_Func_CancelAutoLock (0)
03-21 20:42:25.120: I/caladbolg(153): 3649386537 cald_camctrl.c                    (4588)  4226 P [SVR] -645580759 - Cald_CamCtrl_ICamera_CancelAutoLock (0)
03-21 20:42:25.120: I/caladbolg(153): 3649387911 cald_capctrl.c                    (6371)  4228 P [CAP] -645579385 + Cald_CapCtrl_FSM_Func_StopPreview
03-21 20:42:25.120: I/caladbolg(153): 3649387972 cald_hal_qct.c                    (3054)  4228 P [HAL] -645579324 + Cald_Hal_Qct_If_StopPreview
03-21 20:42:25.120: I/caladbolg(153): 3649388399 cald_hal_qct.c                    (3087)  4228 P [HAL] -645578928 - Cald_Hal_Qct_If_StopPreview (0)
03-21 20:42:25.120: I/caladbolg(153): 3649388429 cald_hal_qct.c                    (7007)  4228 P [HAL] -645578867 + Cald_Hal_Qct_If_DeleteImageConvert
03-21 20:42:25.120: W/ActivityManager(288): Force removing ActivityRecord{2c3a2d88 myapp.mobile.test/.Tutorial3Activity}: app died, no saved state
03-21 20:42:25.130: D/kernel(145): [ 3658.451507] binder: send failed reply for transaction 207652 to 153:4245
03-21 20:42:25.130: E/kernel(145): [ 3658.451538] binder: release proc 4211, transaction 207653, not freed
03-21 20:42:25.130: D/kernel(145): [ 3658.452362] binder: 288:514 transaction failed 29189, size 56-0
03-21 20:42:25.130: D/kernel(145): [ 3658.452514] binder: 288:514 transaction failed 29189, size 56-0
03-21 20:42:25.130: I/caladbolg(153): 3649389681 cald_hal_qct.c                    (7    036)  4228 P [HAL] -645577646 - Cald_Hal_Qct_If_DeleteImageConvert (0)
03-21 20:42:25.130: I/caladbolg(153): 3649390047 cald_capctrl.c                    (6382)  4228 P [CAP] -645577280 - Cald_CapCtrl_FSM_Func_StopPreview
03-21 20:42:25.130: I/caladbolg(153): 3649392336 cald_camctrl.c                    (6729)  4226 P [SVR] -645574960 + Cald_CamCtrl_PowerDown
03-21 20:42:25.130: I/caladbolg(153): 3649392397 cald_camctrl.c                    (7575)  4226 P [SVR] -645574899 + Cald_CamCtrl_FSM_Func_PowerDown
03-21 20:42:25.130: I/caladbolg(153): 3649393984 cald_hal_qct.c                    (2863)  4226 P [HAL] -645573312 + Cald_Hal_Qct_If_PowerDown
03-21 20:42:25.140: I/WindowManager(288): WIN DEATH: Window{2c6f27f8 myapp.mobile.test/myapp.mobile.test.Tutorial3Activity paused=false}
03-21 20:42:25.140: W/WindowManager(288): Force-removing child win Window{2c7015e8 SurfaceView paused=false} from container Window{2c6f27f8 myapp.mobile.test/myapp.mobile.test.Tutorial3Activity paused=false}
03-21 20:42:25.150: W/WindowManager(288): Failed looking up window
03-21 20:42:25.150: W/WindowManager(288): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.os.BinderProxy@2c611a40 does not exist
03-21 20:42:25.150: W/WindowManager(288):   at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:7165)
03-21 20:42:25.150: W/WindowManager(288):   at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:7156)
03-21 20:42:25.150: W/WindowManager(288):   at com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied(WindowState.java:1545)
03-21 20:42:25.150: W/WindowManager(288):   at android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice(Binder.java:417)
03-21 20:42:25.150: W/WindowManager(288):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
03-21 20:42:25.150: D/SurfaceFlinger(136): Release buffer at 0x5e3c8
03-21 20:42:25.150: D/SurfaceFlinger(136): Release buffer at 0x5f758
03-21 20:42:25.150: D/SurfaceFlinger(136): Release buffer at 0x5f758
03-21 20:42:25.150: D/SurfaceFlinger(136): Release buffer at 0x5e3c8
03-21 20:42:25.150: I/WindowManager(288): WIN DEATH: null
03-21 20:42:25.160: I/InputReader(288): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000004
03-21 20:42:25.160: I/InputReader(288): Device reconfigured: id=7, name='cy8ctma300_touch', surface size is now 480x854, mode is 1
03-21 20:42:25.160: I/InputReader(288): Device reconfigured: id=8, name='atdaemon', surface size is now 480x854, mode is 3
03-21 20:42:25.180: D/Zygote(137): Process 4211 terminated by signal (8)
03-21 20:42:25.180: I/ActivityManager(288): Config changed: {1.0 230mcc2mnc en_CA layoutdir=0 sw320dp w320dp h544dp nrml long port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h theme=ComponentInfo{com.sonyericsson.defaultruntimethemes/com.sonyericsson.defaultruntimethemes.GreenThemeService} s.10}
03-21 20:42:25.220: D/GestureDetector(465): touchSlop:35 doubleTapSlop:195
03-21 20:42:25.380: W/InputManagerService(288): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 4211 uid 10068
03-21 20:42:25.390: D/kernel(145): [ 3658.712097] binder: 465:465 transaction failed 29189, size 92-0
03-21 20:42:25.520: D/dalvikvm(367): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1092K, 35% free 10058K/15367K, paused 2ms+4ms
03-21 20:42:25.700: I/caladbolg(153): 3649959505 cald_hal_qct.c                    (2891)  4226 P [HAL] -645007822 - Cald_Hal_Qct_If_PowerDown (0)
03-21 20:42:25.700: I/caladbolg(153): 3649962282 cald_camctrl.c                    (7613)  4226 P [SVR] -645005014 - Cald_CamCtrl_FSM_Func_PowerDown (0)
03-21 20:42:25.700: I/caladbolg(153): 3649962496 cald_camctrl.c                    (6734)  4226 P [SVR] -645004800 - Cald_CamCtrl_PowerDown (0)
03-21 20:42:25.710: W/CameraService(153): native_window_api_disconnect failed: Broken pipe (-32)
03-21 20:42:25.710: I/CameraService(153): Destroying camera 0
03-21 20:42:25.710: W/AudioFlinger(153): session id 61 not found for pid 153
03-21 20:42:25.720: W/AudioFlinger(153): session id 62 not found for pid 153
03-21 20:42:26.070: D/kernel(145): [ 3659.388    031] bq27520 0-0055: bq27520_handle_soc_worker() capacity=82 (82) flags=0x129 ctrl_status=0x28b soh_state=0x3, valid=1
03-21 20:42:27.840: D/dalvikvm(288): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1915K, 22% free 17867K/22727K, paused 11ms+10ms
03-21 20:42:30.480: I/ActivityManager(288): No longer want idv.wangyik.MissedCallReminder (pid 2963): hidden #16
03-21 20:42:30.490: W/ActivityManager(288): Scheduling restart of crashed service idv.wangyik.MissedCallReminder/.AlarmTool in 5000ms
03-21 20:42:35.510: I/ActivityManager(288): Start proc idv.wangyik.MissedCallReminder for service idv.wangyik.MissedCallReminder/.AlarmTool: pid=4270 uid=10128 gids={}
03-21 20:42:35.520: I/dalvikvm(4270): Turning on JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 8...
03-21 20:42:38.220: E/kernel(145): [ 3671.541442] simple_remote_pf simple_remote_pf.0: simple_remote_pf_button_handler - Button callback not registered
03-21 20:42:38.370: D/lights(288): set_light_backlight: brightness=0
03-21 20:42:38.370: I/power(288): *** set_screen_state 0
```

What could be wrong?